# Sagemaker Model is trying to find an old docker image

Tags: docker, amazon-sagemaker

I'm stuck in a situation where Sagemaker is looking for a docker image in ECS registry which I had to remove and I can't figure out how to make it forget about that.

I had to rebuild a docker with torchserve for Sagemaker. I removed the old one (let's call it `torchserve-old-name`, and uploaded a new `torchserve:v2`. For some weird reason SM is still looking for the old one.

```
from sagemaker.model import Model
from sagemaker.predictor import Predictor

image = "134244564256.dkr.ecr.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/torchserve:v2"
model_data = "s3://my-models/torchserve/my-model.tar.gz"
sm_model_name = 'my-model'

print(f"docker image: {image}")
# docker image: 134244564256.dkr.ecr.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/torchserve:v2

torchserve_model = Model(model_data = model_data, 
                         image_uri = image,
                         role  = role,
                         predictor_cls=Predictor,
                         name  = sm_model_name)
endpoint_name = 'torchserve-endpoint-' + time.strftime("%Y-%m-%d-%H-%M-%S", time.gmtime())

predictor = torchserve_model.deploy(instance_type='ml.m4.xlarge',
                                    initial_instance_count=1,
                                    endpoint_name = endpoint_name)
```

Results in:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
UnexpectedStatusException                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-12-67fff0e32d2d> in <module>
      3 predictor = torchserve_model.deploy(instance_type='ml.m4.xlarge',
      4                                     initial_instance_count=1,
----> 5                                     endpoint_name = endpoint_name)

~/anaconda3/envs/python3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sagemaker/model.py in deploy(self, initial_instance_count, instance_type, serializer, deserializer, accelerator_type, endpoint_name, tags, kms_key, wait, data_capture_config, **kwargs)
    762             kms_key=kms_key,
    763             wait=wait,
--> 764             data_capture_config_dict=data_capture_config_dict,
    765         )
    766 

~/anaconda3/envs/python3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sagemaker/session.py in endpoint_from_production_variants(self, name, production_variants, tags, kms_key, wait, data_capture_config_dict)
   3454 
   3455             self.sagemaker_client.create_endpoint_config(**config_options)
-> 3456         return self.create_endpoint(endpoint_name=name, config_name=name, tags=tags, wait=wait)
   3457 
   3458     def expand_role(self, role):

~/anaconda3/envs/python3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sagemaker/session.py in create_endpoint(self, endpoint_name, config_name, tags, wait)
   2957         )
   2958         if wait:
-> 2959             self.wait_for_endpoint(endpoint_name)
   2960         return endpoint_name
   2961 

~/anaconda3/envs/python3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sagemaker/session.py in wait_for_endpoint(self, endpoint, poll)
   3243                 ),
   3244                 allowed_statuses=["InService"],
-> 3245                 actual_status=status,
   3246             )
   3247         return desc
 UnexpectedStatusException: Error hosting endpoint torchserve-endpoint-2021-02-06-21-39-31: Failed. Reason: 
 The repository 'torchserve-old-name' does not exist in the registry with id '134244564256'..
```

I am 100% sure that the old image 'torchserve-old-name' has not been mentioned in this code. I've restarted and re-ran notebook.

Where is it cached, and how can I clear that cache? Sagemaker function documentation doesn't seem to mention it.

Comment: You might need to update the old model or delete and recreate the model